# React Native SQLite Initialisation problem

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sqlite

I have this problem on my react native project with SQLite. Cannot initialise db, I did all the steps, as I also don't know where db created file is located, it shows me an error "TypeError: db.transaction is not a function (it is undefined)"

Comment: `   const db = SQLite.openDatabase({name : "db"},()=>{console.log("success")},()=>{console.log('error')})
    db.transaction(
      (tx)=>{
        tx.executeSql(
          "CREATE TABLE Test IF NOT EXISTS (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name VARCHAR(100) NULL )",[]
          ,()=>{
            console.log("sss")
          },
          (error) =>{console.log("error getting data")}
        )
      }
    )`